# Recursion returning function without returning in special cases

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to combine a given password by bruteforce. So I decided to use recursion function which returns `string`

```
string bruteforce(string password, string forcedPassword)
{
    if (password.length() == forcedPassword.length())
    {
        if (password == forcedPassword)
        {
            return forcedPassword;
        }
        // What can I do here to return nothing and continue from the previous step?
    }

    for (int j = 32; j <= 126; j++)
    {
        forcedPassword += char(j);
        bruteforce(password, forcedPassword);
    }
}

int main()
{
   ...
   cin >> password;
   cout << bruteforce(password, "");
   ...
}
```

The problem is when I get `password.length() == forcedPassword.length()` but they are not the same. I need to exit only the last step of the recursion without any returning values. Is there any way to make it?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to construct the string in recursion? Why not start with the string length that is equal to password?

Comment: This is not your only problem, you don't return in other path too.

Comment: For the particular question (ignoring any other problems), change the signature to: bool bruteforce(string const &, string const &, string &), return true if done false otherwise. Or maybe you need three return paths in which case you would need an int or enum instead of bool.

Comment: Your algorithm assumes you already know the length of the password. Is that really what you want? If not, you should be able to make a recursive brute force algorithm that doesn't check the length.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming non empty password (else use `optional`), you may write:

```
std::string bruteforce(const std::string& password, const std::string& forcedPassword)
{
    if (password.length() == forcedPassword.length())
    {
        if (password == forcedPassword)
        {
            return forcedPassword;
        }
        return "";
    }

    for (int j = 32; j <= 126; j++)
    {
        auto res = bruteforce(password, forcedPassword + char(j));
        if (!res.empty()) {
            return res;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Your code also causes overflow. I tried to modify it and still the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you or not in your specific case:

```
std::string bruteforce( const std::string& enteredPassword, std::string& forcedPassword ) {

    if ( enteredPassword.length() == forcedPassword.length() ) {
        if ( enteredPassword == forcedPassword ) {
            return forcedPassword;
        }    
        return "";
    }    

    static int j = 31;
    while ( j <= 126 ) {
        ++j;
        // Display forcedPassword to test it for each recursive iteration
        std::cout << forcedPassword << "\n";
        return bruteforce( enteredPassword, forcedPassword + char( j ) );    
    }    
    return "";      
}

int main() {    
    std::string password;
    std::string forcedPassword( "Hello" );
    std::cout << "Enter the password\n";
    std::cin >> password;

    std::cout << bruteforce( password, forcedPassword );

    std::cout << "\Press any key and enter to quit.\n";
    char q;
    std::cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

But this does compile, build and run without errors, and there is no stack overflow here.

I made the `enteredPassword` a `const ref` since it will not be modified by this function. For the `forcedPassword` since you are showing that you are concatenating to this string I choose to make this a `non const reference` that will be modified. Instead of a for loop from `[32,126]`, I choose to use a while loop using a `static int` counter. I initially set this value to `31` and check this loop while it is `<= 126`. Then within the loop I `pre-increment` the `static` counter, I then display the `forcedPassword` value for debugging purposes. Finally I return this recursive function passing in the original non modified `enteredPassword` along with the `forcedPassword` while updating it with `char(j)`. For control paths where there are `no operations to be made` I simply just returned `"";`

Answer (score 0):

Using bool function as suggested in comments you can do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool bruteforce(const string& password, string& forcedPassword, unsigned int length=0)
{
    if (password.length() == length)
    {
        if (password == forcedPassword)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    for (int j = 32; j <= 126; ++j)
    {
        forcedPassword[length] = char(j);
        if ((bruteforce(password, forcedPassword, length+1)))
            return true;
    }
}

std::string findpassword(const string& password) {
    std::string forcedPassword = "";
    while (forcedPassword.length() < password.length())
        forcedPassword.push_back('a');
    if (bruteforce(password, forcedPassword))
        return forcedPassword;
    else
        return "failed";
}

int main()
{
   std::string password;
   cin >> password;
   cout << findpassword(password);
}
```